# Logback: replacing 10 digit number by ******** and last two digit

Tags: regex, logging, logback

I use the following in my pattern(logback.xml) to replace 10 digit numbers in my log.

```
%replace(%msg){'\d{10}','**********'}
```

One problem with this approach is, it also matches first 10 digits of 11 digit number. 
 Is there a way to match exactly 10 digits numbers.

Now the bigger problem is somehow I need to display the last two digits of this 10 digit number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To *display* (leave uncaptured) the last two digits, please see the following regex:

```
'\b\d{8}(?=\d{2}\b)'
```

[View a regex demo!](http://regex101.com/r/lP2hO0/3)

This will find 8 numerical digits before two digits where the 10 digits are wrapped within word boundaries. Since `(?= )` is positive lookahead assertion, it won't be matched. The entire match can then be replaced with:

```
********
```

No capturing groups necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
%replace(%msg){'\b\d{10}\b','**********'}
```

`\b` is a word boundary that matches a position where one side is a letter, and the other side is not a letter (for instance a space character, or the beginning of the string)

Comment: any way to display last two digits?

Answer (score 1):

To get the last two digits of the corressponding 10 digit number,

```
'\b\d{8}(\d{2})\b'
```

First captured group contains the last two digits.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lP2hO0/2)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you use this (as @zx81 said):

```
\b\d{8}(\d\d)\b
```

(*Explenation*: http://www.regexper.com/#%5Cb%5Cd%7B8%7D(%5Cd%5Cd)%5Cb)

That will find 10 digits and store the last 2 digits in a group. If you replace that with a string like this:

```
********$1
```

That will replace the first 8 numbers, and leave the last two visible.
Example: http://regexr.com/3989s